# Sympy extend the length of a Line Segment

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

I'm trying to use **Sympy** to calculate a point along an extended line segment.

So first I'm setting up a line `Segment` between point_a and point_b:

```
from sympy import Point, Segment

point_a = (4, 1)
point_b = (10, 3)

p1, p2 = Point(point_a), Point(point_b)
seg = Segment(p1, p2)
```

In this example the length of the segment is approx `6.32455532034`

I want to be able to keep `point_a` where it is but extend `point_b` out so that the length of the segment is `20` (instead of `6.32`)

```
seg.length = 20
new_end_point = seg.points[1]
```

However it does not allow the length of the line to be changed like this.  Is there a simple way I can do this?

*Note 1: that I'm trying to use Sympy for this in order to keep the code readable for non-math people (such as myself)*

*Note 2: `20` is an arbrary length not related to the starting distance between p1 and p2*

Thanks to @smichr for the answer, I have added a simplified version of what he said:

```
from sympy import Point, Ray, Circle

point_a = (4, 1)
point_b = (10, 3)
extend = 20

p1, p2 = Point(point_a), Point(point_b)
ray = Ray(p1, p2)
c = Circle(p1, extend).intersection(ray)

# The resulting point
result = c[0].evalf().coordinates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a segment defined by points

```
>>> p1=(0,0)
>>> p2=(1,0)
>>> s=Segment(p1,p2)
```

Cast it to a Ray and see where it intersects the Circle of desired radius, centered on p1. It will only intersect at one point, so use that point for your new segment:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import t
>>> from sympy import Ray, Circle
>>> Circle(p1, 20).intersection(Ray(*s.args))[0]
Point(20, 0)
>>> new_segment = Segment(p1, _)
```

You could wrap this into a function like this:

```
>>> def directed_segment(line, length):
...     from sympy import Circle, Ray
...     p3 = Ray(*line.args).intersection(Circle(line.p1, length))[0]
...     return line.func(line.p1, p3)
...
>>> directed_segment(s,20)
Segment2D(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(20, 0))
```

The simplest approach is to just scale the segment in both directions wrt the desired point (first arg, in your case). The scale factor will be your desired length, `l`, divided by the current length. A helper function named `new_seg` is defined below and used to lengthen a 3,4,5 hypotenuse to a length of 10 while maintaining the initial point of the segment:

```py
new_seg=lambda s,l : s.scale(*[l/s.length]*2, s.args[0])
>>> new_seg(Segment((1,2),(4,6)), 10)
Segment2D(Point2D(1, 2), Point2D(7, 10))
>>> assert _.length == 10
```

If you used `s.midpoint` instead of `s.args[0]` then the midpoint of the segment would remain the same. For example, to double the length while maintaining the midpoint,

```py
>>> t=s.scale(2,2,s.midpoint)
>>> assert t.length = 2*s.length and t.midpoint == s.midpoint
```

Comment: Thanks....it didn't even occur to me to your the intersection with a circle, that's a really good idea.

Comment: I initial thought of just solving for the parameter like `solve(seg.p1.distance(Line(seg).arbitrary_point(t))-20)`, but that gives two solutions while the use of Ray limits you to one solution. But if you designated `t = Symbol('t', positive=True)` then I think the non-Circle method would work.

Answer (score 1):

What would it mean to change the length of the line? Where would be the new start and end points?

I'll assume that you want to keep `p1` the same but move `p2` so that it is twice as far from `p1` but in the same direction as from `p1` to `p2`:

```
In [12]: p1, p2 = Point2D(4, 1), Point2D(10, 3)

In [13]: p3 = p1 + 2*(p2 - p1)

In [14]: p3
Out[14]: Point2D(16, 5)

In [15]: Segment2D(p1, p3)
Out[15]: Segment2D(Point2D(4, 1), Point2D(16, 5))
```

Alternatively you could make the multiple symbolic and then substitute different values:

```py
In [16]: x = symbols('x')

In [17]: line = Segment2D(p1, p1 + x*(p2 - p1))

In [18]: line
Out[18]: Segment2D(Point2D(4, 1), Point2D(6*x + 4, 2*x + 1))

In [19]: line.subs(x, 2)
Out[19]: Segment2D(Point2D(4, 1), Point2D(16, 5))
```

Comment: Your assumption about keeping p1 where it is and moving p2 is correct, but want to move it so that the line is a specific length.  My example I want to have the resulting line segment be 20 long (not twice the distance of the points, so i find your answer confusing)

Comment: If you use `(p2 - p1)/p2.distance(p1)` then `x` will be the length of the segment.